# List of links not being populated via JSON when I add a target attribute. What would cause to not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering what is happening behinds the scenes and not just asking someone to help me find a typo.

My search feature was working on this [demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/wasjt/).

[image]

But then I added a `target="_blank"` and now is not working. Here is the container

**HTML**

```
<div id="labsContainer" class="sixteen columns row">
  <div id="labs"></div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery that I am using to populate the list dynamically.

**jQuery**

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/101702/labs_1.json', function(data) {
      var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if ((val.name.search(myExp) != -1) ||
        (val.city.search(myExp) != -1)) {

            output += '<li>';

            output += '<h5>'+ val.name +'</h5>';
    output += '<div class="row">';

    output += '<span>' + '<i class="fa fa-building-o">' + '</i>' + '</span>';     
    output += '<span>';
    output += val.city + ',&nbsp;' + val.state + '&nbsp;' + val.country;
    output += '<br />';
    output += '</span>';


    output += '<span>' + '<i class="fa fa-phone">' + '</i>' + '</span>';
    output += '<span>' + val.phone + '</span>';
    output += '<br />';

    output += '<span>' + '<i class="fa fa-desktop">' +'</i>' +'</span>';
    output += '<span>'; 
    output += '<a href="http://'; 
    output += val.website + '"'; 
    output += 'targe="_blank"'; 
    output += '>'; 
    output += val.website; 
    output += '</a>' + '</span>';
    output += '</div>';        
            output += '</li>';
          }
      });
      output += '</ul>';
      $('#labsContainer').html(output);
    });
});
```

When I first made the code, i wrote `output += 'targe="_blank"';` and it worked fine. Then I attempted to correct the typo but then it would not work.

Demo is available here http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/wasjt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I thought it's a missing space before `target` (which is obviously missing), but I got the same error with codepen. Then I checked chromes dev console which says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

at the following line

```
output += ' data-t='_blank'';
```

which is obviously not what you wrote in your javascript. Then I randomly tried some other "spellings" of this javascript part, and it turned out that

```
output += ' target=' + '"_blank"';
```

is working. The term behind `output +=` is obviously the same in both cases, so my only guess is **crazy codepen bug** or I missed something.